# Getting the failed url in a custom 404 error page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to get the URL of the failed request from a custom 404 error page? I'm using IIS to set the custom error page to a .net page where I want to process the failed request.

I've tried using the url and referer attributes from the request object but they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using your web.config to point to a custom error page and leave out the IIS setting. See if you get a Referrer then.

Comment: I tried using the web.config but it only handles .aspx errors and not .html files.

Comment: May I suggest you add that in your question?